# Include username in file name

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a dm support bot in discord.js.

I thought about a DB where for each open ticket I make a .json file in a directory including the date and the username of the person that DM'd the bot.
But, I don't know how to:

1. check for a file with the user's name so that it doesn't keep opening tickets instead of sending the user's message
2. Send the user's message if his ticket is already opened
3. create the .json file when the name isn't found
4. Create a channel for the staff to see

I wish to use the module FS for those things.

EDIT: I went a totaly different way, abd ysed a database. Thanks for helping tho!

Comment: First of all, why not just use a regular database? Using a database such as Mongo wouldn't just make this whole process easier, but would let you store so much more information to confirm this user has a ticket open. Second, this whole question sounds like a "Here's what I want to do, now do it for me." StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. What have you tried already? What errors have you come across? etc.

Comment: @ItamarS Well that's not what I mean, the problem is I don't really know how to use Mongo. And no, I don't want people to write it for me.

Comment: Considering the biggest part of Discord Bots revolves around database support and saving information, maybe it's a good chance to start learning. If you "don't want people to write it for you", what are you asking for this in question?

Comment: @Zariaa_: Try [Enmap](//npmjs.com/enmap). It was meant for your use case.

Comment: I am mostly asking _how_ to do said stuff, and not to do it for me. I'm more or so asking for a "starter pack", I don't really know how to explain it. I'm gonna try to use Mongo Tho

Comment: The problem here is if you write too fast to the file, you can corrupt data. Databases like Enmap (uses sqlite) are protected from these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is suggested that you use a proper Database, instead of using Local JSON Files for Data Storage. The reason for that are Multiple:

- You can't transfer Data Easily from one hosting to another
- Bound by storage limits of your Bot Hosting
- Using a Database, such as MongoDB or SQL, will make it easier to read, write and update data.

Also, using username for serialization is not a good idea, since 9999 people can have the same username (but not the same tag) on Discord. It is better to use the User ID, since that is unique to every individual.

Assuming that you still want to try out storing in local JSON, what you will want to do is that, make a directory for storing all your tickets first. Something named Tickets, or something on the lines of that.

The template for the file name which we will follow is: `${UserID}-${GuildID}.json`

- Checking if the file exists
  You can use the [fs.existsSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path) method to check if your user has a ticket. Your General Path would be `Path/To/Tickets/${UserID}-${GuildID}.json`. If that file exists, you can say that the ticket's open
- Writing to the File
  You can use the [fs.writeFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) method to write new file OR update data. The data parameter in our case has to be a STRING, so please use `JSON.stringify(YourTicketData)` to write the data in your file. You can read more about JSON.stringify [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).
  By the way, if you wanted to like view your data on your own manually, then it is suggested you pretty print it using `JSON.stringify(YourTicketData, null, "\t")` instead.
- You can make channels using the `<Guild>.channels.create`. You can read about it [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager) in the Discord.js Documentation.
  So how'll we use it in this case is,

```js
<Guild>.channels.create(`${UserID}-${GuildID}`, {
    type: "text",
    topic: `Ticket Channel for ${User Tag}`,
    permissionOverwrites: permSettings,
});
```

The perm settings will be the settings for the ticket channel. Of course you can change the Channel Name to your own preferences however.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to what RishiMath said, you can use fs.writeFile to create and write the data to the file,

```
const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.member.user
const userid = guild.members.cache.get(user.id)
const user_file = userid + ".json"
fs.writeFile(user_file, your_data_var, (err) => {
    if (err) {console.log("error"), err}
    console.log("file for " + userid + " has been written")
})
```

I would suggest getting [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) (npm i fs-extra) as it can be very useful when trying to ensure files exist before doing anything to them

```
const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.member.user
const userid = guild.members.cache.get(user.id)
user_file = __dirname + \\userid + ".json"
fs.ensureFile(user_file, (err) => {
    if (err) {console.log("error"), err}
})
```

for reading the file you can use this instead of doing it manually

```
const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.member.user
const userid = guild.members.cache.get(user.id)
const user_file = userid + ".json"
fs.readFile(user_file, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {console.log("error"), err}
    const channel = <client>.channels.cache.get('<id>');
    channel.send("file " + user_file + " contains " + data);
})
```

I just did some googling and copying and pasting for the discord.js parts so they might not work but everything else should work

Comment: fs.stat is the replacement for fs.exists